# how can i set a title(once) for all activities?

Tags: android, titlebar

I wish to set the title of each activity with a constant value which is fetched from a local sqlite database.  the value is the user's username.

Is there a way to set the title once and have it affect all activities? or do I have to manually set the title on each activity?

If there is a way, how is it achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One obvious way could be creating your own `MyActivity` class extending `Activity`, and in `onCreate()` of it call `setTitle()`. Then extend all your activites from `MyActivity` instead of `Activity` and call `super.onCreate()`.